# What is the correct text type for setting OleVariant text properties

Tags: string, ole-automation, c++builder-10.4-sydney

The code below used to work when compiled on C++Builder 6.0:

```
    Variant xlApp, wBook, wSheet, vRange;

    String xlFile  = "C:\\Temp\\ExcelTestFile.xlsx",
           xlTitle = "Relatório de Geração";
    try{
        xlApp = CreateOleObject("Excel.Application");
        // Hide Excel
        xlApp.OlePropertySet("Visible", false);
        // Add new Workbook
        xlApp.OlePropertyGet("WorkBooks").OleFunction("Add", -4167);
        // Get WorkBook
        wBook = xlApp.OlePropertyGet("Workbooks").OlePropertyGet("Item", 1);

        // Get WorkSheet
        wSheet = wBook.OlePropertyGet("Worksheets").OlePropertyGet("Item", 1);
        wSheet.OlePropertySet("Name", xlTitle.c_str() ); // Raise Incorrect Type
    }
    catch(Exception &E){
         ShowMessage( E.Message );
         xlApp.OlePropertySet("DisplayAlerts",false);
         xlApp.OleProcedure("Quit");
    }
```

What is the correct string type?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type when passing strings through COM is `WideString`.

The `WideString` type is actually a wrapper around the Windows `BSTR` type, which means behind the scenes it uses the functions:

- [**SysAllocString**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysallocstring)
- [**SysFreeString**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysfreestring)

You don't **have** to use `WideString`; but you **do** have to use **SysAllocString** and **SysFreeString**. You can call them manually, or you can use `WideString` to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

> `wSheet.OlePropertySet("Name", xlTitle.c_str() ); // Raise Incorrect Type`

The C++Builer 6 code was using `AnsiString` and passed a `const char*` from it to `OlePropertySet()`.  Now, in modern versions, the code would be using `UnicodeString` and passing its `const wchar_t*` instead.

However, the COM object expect a `BSTR` string instead (which is an alias for `wchar_t*`, but its memory is managed by the OS, not the RTL).  The RTL *should* b converting from `char*`/`wchar_t*` to `BSTR` automatically for you, but to help it along you should use the `WideString` class instead (which wraps a `BSTR`), eg:

```cpp
wSheet.OlePropertySet("Name", WideString(xlTitle).c_bstr() );
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
wSheet.OlePropertySet("Name", WideString(xlTitle) );
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
wSheet.OlePropertySet<WideString>("Name", xlTitle );
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
WideString xlTitle;
....
wSheet.OlePropertySet("Name", xlTitle );
```

---

That being said, `BSTR` handling in `TAutoArgs` (which `OlePropertySet()` uses internally) seems to have broken somewhere between C++Builder 10.4.2 to 11.2, see this discussion:

[WideString.c_bstr() operation in 11.2](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/8199-widestringc_bstr-operation-in-112/)